# How can I output the contents of cells in my spreadsheet to a txt file?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet looking like this with three columns A, B and C:

```
1   41309.5 の
2   23509.54    に
3   22216.8 は
```

What I need to do is to create a text file where each line of the file looks like this:

```
 Insert into freqleeds (id, freq, text) values ( 1, 41309.5, 'の')
 ..
```

Can someone give me some idea as to how I can do this?

Comment: Do you try to export data to text file?

Comment: I didn't try that but what I need is to get some filler words before and after the actual data. I am not sure how to do that. I guess to someone who knows Excel then it's easy, but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using VBA or even complex functions, you can create a support column at column D, with the following formula that will [`Concatenate()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d) your template with the variables:

```
="Insert into freqleeds (id, freq, text) values (" & A1 & "," & B1 & "," & C1 & ")"
```

After pasting this formula in your D1 cell, you can drag it down, to create the specific db statements for each row.

[image]

After that, you should select the whole D column and copy it:

[image]

Then you should paste the content into a notepad.

[image]

Done.

**P.s.:** If you want to automate this job, you can create a macro to apply this concatenate function to each line with content in your spreadsheet, filter them according to your needs and [export this specific column to a txt file](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/write-data-to-text-file.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Sub test()

 Dim Ws As Worksheet, i As Long, Fr As Long, Lr As Long, St0 As String, St As String

 Set Ws = ActiveSheet
 St0 = "Insert into freqleeds (id, freq, text) values ( "

 Fr = 1 'First row
 Lr = Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 

 For i = Fr To Lr
  St = St & St0 & Ws.Cells(i, 1) & ", " & Ws.Cells(i, 2) & ", '" & Ws.Cells(i, 3) & "')" & vbNewLine
 Next

 With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    .CreateTextFile("d:\00000.txt", True, True).Write St ' change the file name
 End With

End Sub
```